# Cómo alinear botones correctamente a la misma altura en boostrap

Tags: html5, bootstrap, css3, mediaqueries

Necesito alinear botones a la misma altura pero hay textos más grandes que otros y me resulta imposible. ¿Que solución habría?

Os dejo el código:

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

<div class="row">
  <div class="container tablaquehacemos">
    <div class="col-sm-12 col-md-6 col-lg-3">
      <div class="card text-xs-center">
        <img class="card-img-top img-fluid imagehacemos m-x-auto" src="images/iconotablet.jpg" alt="Card image cap">
        <div class="card-block turismo">
          <h4 class="card-title">TURISMO TECNOLOGICO Y CIENTIFICO</h4>
          <p class="card-text">¿Te apetecería descubrir tesoros ocultos, transportarte al pasado y sentirte como un arqueólogo gracias a las nuevas tecnologías?.</p>
          <a href="#" class="btn btn-primary">Go somewhere</a>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-sm-12 col-md-6 col-lg-3">
      <div class="card text-xs-center">
        <img class="card-img-top img-fluid imagehacemos m-x-auto" src="images/iconolapiz.jpg" alt="Card image cap">
        <div class="card-block didactica">
          <h4 class="card-title">DIDÁCTICA DEL PATRIMONIO</h4>
          <p class="card-text">Renovamos el concepto de taller pedagógico y de la visita cultural incluyendo en nuestras propuestas escolares el uso de tablets digitales para fomentar un uso didáctico y responsable de las nuevas tecnologías entre l@s alumn@s.</p>
          <a href="#" class="btn btn-primary">Go somewhere</a>
        </div>
      </div>

    </div>
    <div class="col-sm-12 col-md-6 col-lg-3">
      <div class="card text-xs-center">
        <img class="card-img-top img-fluid imagehacemos m-x-auto" src="images/iconoojo.png" alt="Card image cap">
        <div class="card-block culturales">
          <h4 class="card-title">PROYECTOS CULTURALES</h4>
          <p class="card-text">Una de nuestras señas de identidad es complementar cualquier tipo de actividad con la cultura, dotándole así de un componente enriquecedor para este tipo de actos.</p>
          <a href="#" class="btn btn-primary">Go somewhere</a>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-sm-12 col-md-6 col-lg-3">
      <div class="card text-xs-center">
        <img class="card-img-top img-fluid imagehacemos m-x-auto" src="images/iconolupa.png" alt="Card image cap">
        <div class="card-block arqueologia">
          <h4 class="card-title">ARQUEOLOGÍA</h4>
          <p class="card-text">Nos avalan más de 10 años en el mundo de la arqueología lo que nos hace profundos conocedores de la realidad del trabajo arqueológico y de su gestión.</p>
          <a href="#" class="btn btn-primary">Go somewhere</a>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Nos explicas mejor con lo que dices alinear a la misma altura?, a la atura de que?, por favor

Comment: que los 4 botones queden a la misma altura del texto mas largo

Comment: Con qué versión de bootstrap?

Comment: estoy usando la 4, y estoy haciendolo con las cards,

Comment: Veo que el ejemplo está en bootstrap 3.3.6 pero dices que estás usando la versión 4.

Answer (score 4):

Se me ocurren dos opciones, con `display:table` o con flexbox pero hay que modificar un poco el comportamiento de las columnas de Bootstrap.

### **display:table**

El `div` que contiene las columnas llevaría `display:table` y las columnas `display:table-cell`, luego habría que eliminar los float y posicionar el boton de forma absoluta alineado abajo. El problema es que las cuatro columnas están en la misma fila y tú tienes dos o cuatro columnas según la resolución, se complicaría intentar solucionar eso.

```css
.tablaquehacemos{
  display:table;
  }

.tablaquehacemos .col-md-6, .tablaquehacemos .col-lg-3{
  display:table-cell;
  float:none;
  }

.tablaquehacemos a.btn{
  position:absolute;
  bottom:-10px;
  }
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

<div class="row">
  <div class="container tablaquehacemos">
    <div class="col-sm-12 col-md-6 col-lg-3">
      <div class="card text-xs-center">
        <img class="card-img-top img-fluid imagehacemos m-x-auto" src="images/iconotablet.jpg" alt="Card image cap">
        <div class="card-block turismo">
          <h4 class="card-title">TURISMO TECNOLOGICO Y CIENTIFICO</h4>
          <p class="card-text">¿Te apetecería descubrir tesoros ocul;tos, transportarte al pasado y sentirte como un arqueólogo gracias a las nuevas tecnologías?.</p>
          <a href="#" class="btn btn-primary">Go somewhere</a>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-sm-12 col-md-6 col-lg-3">
      <div class="card text-xs-center">
        <img class="card-img-top img-fluid imagehacemos m-x-auto" src="images/iconolapiz.jpg" alt="Card image cap">
        <div class="card-block didactica">
          <h4 class="card-title">DIDÁCTICA DEL PATRIMONIO</h4>
          <p class="card-text">Renovamos el concepto de taller pedagógico y de la visita cultural incluyendo en nuestras propuestas escolares el uso de tablets digitales para fomentar un uso didáctico y responsable de las nuevas tecnologías entre l@s alumn@s.</p>
          <a href="#" class="btn btn-primary">Go somewhere</a>
        </div>
      </div>

    </div>
    <div class="col-sm-12 col-md-6 col-lg-3">
      <div class="card text-xs-center">
        <img class="card-img-top img-fluid imagehacemos m-x-auto" src="images/iconoojo.png" alt="Card image cap">
        <div class="card-block culturales">
          <h4 class="card-title">PROYECTOS CULTURALES</h4>
          <p class="card-text">Una de nuestras señas de identidad es complementar cualquier tipo de actividad con la cultura, dotándole así de un componente enriquecedor para este tipo de actos.</p>
          <a href="#" class="btn btn-primary">Go somewhere</a>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-sm-12 col-md-6 col-lg-3">
      <div class="card text-xs-center">
        <img class="card-img-top img-fluid imagehacemos m-x-auto" src="images/iconolupa.png" alt="Card image cap">
        <div class="card-block arqueologia">
          <h4 class="card-title">ARQUEOLOGÍA</h4>
          <p class="card-text">Nos avalan más de 10 años en el mundo de la arqueología lo que nos hace profundos conocedores de la realidad del trabajo arqueológico y de su gestión.</p>
          <a href="#" class="btn btn-primary">Go somewhere</a>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

### **Flexbox**

Con flexbox es mucho más sencillo, `display:flex` al `div` que contiene las columnas, `flex-wrap:wrap` para que las cajas caigan si no hay espacio, posicionar el boton abajo y dar un poco de margen inferior para cuando haya dos columnas:

```css
.tablaquehacemos{
  display:flex;
  flex-wrap:wrap;
  }

.tablaquehacemos .col-md-6, .tablaquehacemos .col-lg-3{
  margin-bottom: 50px;
}
.tablaquehacemos a.btn{
  position:absolute;
  bottom:-30px;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

<div class="row">
  <div class="container tablaquehacemos">
    <div class="col-sm-12 col-md-6 col-lg-3">
      <div class="card text-xs-center">
        <img class="card-img-top img-fluid imagehacemos m-x-auto" src="images/iconotablet.jpg" alt="Card image cap">
        <div class="card-block turismo">
          <h4 class="card-title">TURISMO TECNOLOGICO Y CIENTIFICO</h4>
          <p class="card-text">¿Te apetecería descubrir tesoros ocultos, transportarte al pasado y sentirte como un arqueólogo gracias a las nuevas tecnologías?.</p>
          <a href="#" class="btn btn-primary">Go somewhere</a>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-sm-12 col-md-6 col-lg-3">
      <div class="card text-xs-center">
        <img class="card-img-top img-fluid imagehacemos m-x-auto" src="images/iconolapiz.jpg" alt="Card image cap">
        <div class="card-block didactica">
          <h4 class="card-title">DIDÁCTICA DEL PATRIMONIO</h4>
          <p class="card-text">Renovamos el concepto de taller pedagógico y de la visita cultural incluyendo en nuestras propuestas escolares el uso de tablets digitales para fomentar un uso didáctico y responsable de las nuevas tecnologías entre l@s alumn@s.</p>
          <a href="#" class="btn btn-primary">Go somewhere</a>
        </div>
      </div>

    </div>
    <div class="col-sm-12 col-md-6 col-lg-3">
      <div class="card text-xs-center">
        <img class="card-img-top img-fluid imagehacemos m-x-auto" src="images/iconoojo.png" alt="Card image cap">
        <div class="card-block culturales">
          <h4 class="card-title">PROYECTOS CULTURALES</h4>
          <p class="card-text">Una de nuestras señas de identidad es complementar cualquier tipo de actividad con la cultura, dotándole así de un componente enriquecedor para este tipo de actos.</p>
          <a href="#" class="btn btn-primary">Go somewhere</a>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-sm-12 col-md-6 col-lg-3">
      <div class="card text-xs-center">
        <img class="card-img-top img-fluid imagehacemos m-x-auto" src="images/iconolupa.png" alt="Card image cap">
        <div class="card-block arqueologia">
          <h4 class="card-title">ARQUEOLOGÍA</h4>
          <p class="card-text">Nos avalan más de 10 años en el mundo de la arqueología lo que nos hace profundos conocedores de la realidad del trabajo arqueológico y de su gestión.</p>
          <a href="#" class="btn btn-primary">Go somewhere</a>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Divide los textos y los botones en dos `.row` distintos, de esta manera los botones siempre van a estar alineados y el espacio de los textos superiores siempre se va a adaptar a tu texto mas largo.

Comment: eso lo intente pero no me sirve, por que en modo escritorio son 4 juntos alineados, en modo tablet son 2 arriba y 2 abajo alineados, y en modo movil es uno cada uno que es el unico que me sale correctmente tal como esta ahora mismo.